# Could someone figure out why my h1 h2 and button are lower on the third slide than compared to the other slides?

Tags: html, css, flexslider, spacing

Open this with [Firefox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189845951/cuddly%20critters%20v3%20redesign/html/index.html). Not sure yet why it doesn't open correctly in IE or Chrome.

I don't think the CSS is different on the third slide (Gumdrop, one eyed cat's slide).

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="slide" src="" data-image="../images/oneeyecat1.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://wholedesignstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/hand-fandrop-1-lightroom-31.jpg); background-size: cover;            

                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="information easybring">
                        <h1>Gumdrop</h1>
                        <h2>Gumdrop was abused and neglected. She needs you. Visit her today.</h2>
                        <div class="button"><a onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'HompageSlider', 'cta', 'Fandrop']);" href="/work/fandrop">Discover More</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Relevant CSS for the parent div:

```
.information {
display: block;
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1200px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Relevant CSS for the h1

```
.information h1{color:#fff;font-size:50px;text-shadow:0 1px 1px #555;margin-bottom:40px;}
```

Sorry I can't post images yet!

Comment: Post your code and also preferably a fiddle.

Comment: That would be a lot of code. Could you use developer tools and highlight the h1, h2 and button for the third slide?

Comment: Post RELEVANT code not your entire site

Comment: Gosh, ok sorry!! I didn't think F12 on the h1 would be that hard.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce your issue. All h1s, h2s and buttons are at the same height.

Comment: I found the solution. I was missing two properties that the other slides had.     <div class="slide" src="" data-image="../images/doglick1.jpg" style="background-image: url(http://wholedesignstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/whole-design-studios.jpg); background-size: cover; display: block; background-position: center bottom;"> display and background-position were missing. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution.

```
<div class="slide" src="" data-image="../images/doglick1.jpg" style="background-image:        url(wholedesignstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/…); background-size: cover; display: block; background-position: center center;">
```

display and background-position were missing. Thanks for looking! **

Comment: Someone newb like me from Codeacademy helped me. It's kinda sad, stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ is not defined
```

You have to include jquery before calling your jquery library/plugin...

Comment: What about the h1, h2 and button issue on the third slide?

Comment: That's just a comment. Could you help explain what --> has to do with the h1, h2 and button on the third slide?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that in your third slide, the comment tags are not properly wrapped.
Syntax error, basically.

Comment: I corrected that, but still see the h1, h2 and button on the third slide a bit lower than compared to the other slides. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't see the offset anymore after the comments are removed. Just check if you were doing it correctly. Only syntax problem, not a big deal :)

Comment: Are you sure? I didn't upload anything new to dropbox. Could you focus more on the h1 offset issue? I'll correct the commenting. This is just for practice. I'm not getting paid for this or turning this in for homework. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your dropbox URL uses HTTPS (secure), and then you are loading a bunch of scripts from wholedesignstudios.com (non secure). The browser is blocking the non-secure content.

This is the message that Chrome displays:

`[blocked] The page at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189845951/cuddly%20critters%20v3%20redesign/html/index.html ran insecure content from http://wholedesignstudios.com/wp-content/themes/whole/_/js/slider.js.`

Internet Explorer:

`HTTPS security is compromised by http://wholedesignstudios.com/wp-content/themes/whole/_/js/slider.js`

Try moving all these files to your dropbox folder, so that all your assets are loaded from the same domain.

Comment: What about the h1, h2 and button issue on the third slide?

Comment: The slider is broken due to the security problem described above. Start by moving over all the assets from the external domain, to make sure that all your scripts are executing properly.

Comment: Why does the security issue only affect the h1, h2 and button on the third slide? I just don't like the spacing on the h1, h2 and button. Please help. I'm not going to sell this site or turn this in for homework. This is just for practice.

Comment: The security issue had nothing to do with the h1, h2 and button displaying incorrectly. Another newb from Codeacademy helped me. I was missing a display and background-position property. Thanks!